# DTPicker Properties can't set custom date format correctly

Tags: excel

For my Date Time Picker in Excel, I want to change the date format from 7/1/2020 to 2020-01-07 (yyyy-mm-dd).

So I went to DTPicker Properties and set the CustomFormat.

[image]

But when I went to check on the actual box, the date gives me 2020-00-07...

[image]

Even when I change the month to February, the month still remains 00. Same for when I move back to 2019.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Seems as if the `mm` in the format is not taken in correct context here. It seems to be interpreted to be minutes instead of month. Try `yyyy-MM-dd` using a uppercase M.

Comment: Wow that's dumb... Been banging my head on this for hours and that's the cause..